# Haskell question about function

Tags: haskell, inferred-type

Working out of RWH, Chapter 3 question 5 requests I create a function to test for the existence of a paldindrome.

I wrote this, but it doesn't work

```
pCheck :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool;
pCheck a = take n a == ( take n $ reverse a )
  where n = floor ( length a / 2 )
```

I get this error when I try to run it:

```
No instance for (RealFrac Int)
  arising from a use of `floor' at len.hs:13:11-32
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (RealFrac Int)
In the expression: floor (length a / 2)
In the definition of `n': n = floor (length a / 2)
In the definition of `pCheck':
    pCheck a = take n a == (take n $ reverse a)
             where
                 n = floor (length a / 2)
```

I'm confused what am I doing wrong? I know a paldindrome could just as well be tested with `a == reverse a`, but now I want to find the error in my way.

UPDATE: one of the errors with the code was fixed by a suggestion by Justice, the question has been updated to reflect the remaining problem

Comment: A simpler test would be: `isPalindrome x = (show x) == (reverse $ show x)`

Comment: re: Jonno, I don't think the show, or parens are needed.
`isPalindrome = x == reverse x`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression

```
take n a == take n $ reverse a
```

gets parsed as

```
(take n a == take n) $ (reverse a)
```

because the `$` operator has precedence `0`, lower even than the `==` operator.

You need the expression:

```
take n a == (take n $ reverse a)
```

Also, please respect the Haskell and use `length a` rather than `length (a)`. You should also use `` length a `div` 2 `` rather than `length a / 2`. The function `div` is integer division, resulting in an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems.

First, the precedence problem noted by Justice: you need `(take n $ reverse a)` or `take n (reverse a)`

Second, you can only divide rationals, not integers, so you really want

```
  where n = floor $ (toRational $ length $ reverse a) / 2
```

Or, as noted by Justice -- so upvote him rather than me for this -- use integer division `div` instead of `(/)` and then you don't need `toRational`

(It might be possible to get rid of the parens here, but I don't know if it's worth the effort...)

Answer (score 0):

Haskell won't do any kind of automatic conversion between integral and floating point numbers when it sees expressions like `length a / 2`. If you want to divide 2 numbers of type `Int` ignoring any remainders, use `div`.

```
Prelude> 2 `div` 2
1
Prelude> 3 `div` 2
1
Prelude> 4 `div` 2
2
Prelude> 5 `div` 2
2
Prelude>
```